# How to query between date range when both from and to date are optional using JDBI?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbi

I need to query list of orders between from and to dates. Both, these are optional and if not provided should be excluded from `WHERE` clause. I need to achieve this using `JDBI` for Postgres.

ex:

if only from date is provided the query should be:

`SELECT id, total, date, country FROM orders WHERE order date >=:fromDate AND country =:country`

if only to date is provided the query should be:

`SELECT id, total, date, country FROM orders WHERE order date <:toDate AND country =:country`

if both dates are not provided:

`SELECT id, total, date, country FROM orders WHERE country =:country`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try building the query? Also, how do you determine when a single date is passed if it is a fromDate or toDate?

Comment: The examples I have in the application are queries written like  `@SqlQuery(SELECT id, total, date, country FROM orders WHERE country =:country)` in the DAO interfaces. I am not aware of how to build the query. The dates are received as POST of form parameters named fromDate and endDate.

Comment: @Vvn can you please point me to an example of dynamically building the query ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special in JDBI which would let you do this.

Your options are:

1. Check within your code if either parameter is null, and call an appropriate DAO method (you'd need 4 for all possible permutations of null/not null)
2. Some SQL that uses PostgreSQL CASE expression, something like this:

   ```
   SELECT id, total, date, country FROM orders 
   WHERE order_date >= (case when :fromDate is null then 0 else :fromDate end) 
   AND order_date <= (case when :toDate is null then current_date else :toDate end) 
   AND country =:country
   ```